# Oracle PL/SQL Stored procedure Datetime interval precision ORA-30088

Tags: mysql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, syntax-error

I'm having problem in implementing my PL/SQL procedure in assigning my date time format. im referring to my MySQL Stored procedure, i'm new to Oracle PL/SQL.

Here is MY PL/SQL translation from MySQL procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE "DateTimeSP" (xType IN VARCHAR2, xResult OUT VARCHAR2)
AS
BEGIN

CASE
    WHEN xType = 'TIME' THEN 

             SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() FROM dual INTO xResult;

    WHEN xType = 'DATE' THEN 

            SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) FROM dual INTO xResult;

    WHEN xType = 'NOW' THEN 

            ( SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP) FROM dual INTO xResult;

    WHEN xType = 'NOWFORMAT' THEN 

              SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'%m/%d/%Y %l:%i:%s %p') FROM dual INTO xResult;

END CASE;

END;
```

here is my error log

> Datetime interval precision ORA-30088
>   PL/SQL:ORA-00933: sql command not properly ended
>   PL/SQL: SQL statement ignored
>   PLS-00103: encountered the symbol SELECT when expecting one of the following

Comment: You're obviously getting that error message from an Oracle table server, not a MySQL server. But what are you trying to do when you get it?  Compile your PL/SQL proc?  Compile your MySQL proc (which won't work on an Oracle table server)?

Comment: i'd like to compile my PL/SQL proc.. my error log is from my PL/SQL proc. sorry i'll simplify my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have modified your stored procedure just a little bit for Oracle-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE DateTimeSP (xType IN VARCHAR2, xResult OUT VARCHAR2)
AS
BEGIN
    CASE
        WHEN xType = 'TIME' THEN 
            SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'HH24:MI:SS')
              INTO xResult
              FROM dual;
        WHEN xType = 'DATE' THEN 
            SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE)
              INTO xResult  -- Returns date in the default format
              FROM dual;
        WHEN xType = 'NOW' THEN 
           SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP)
             INTO xResult
             FROM dual;
        WHEN xType = 'NOWFORMAT' THEN 
           SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')
             INTO xResult
             FROM dual;
    END CASE;
END;
/
```

Don't forget to read TO_CHAR function in detail on [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm). It is an extremely flexible function for formatting date, time and timestamps.

Comment: In question there is %p - is AM/PM format in MySQL, so in Oracle to_char format you need probably also add "AM" like this: TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss AM')

Comment: @Myshov- it would then be `TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')`. It would be just `HH`, not `HH24`. Edited my answer to accommodate this. Thanks!

Comment: thank you guys my SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() FROM dual INTO xResult;  must be presented with this format SELECT  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP INTO xResult FROM dual;